# Android and Accents Missing

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I've created an EditText and if I assign the property android:text from xml code using a word with accents (I try with àèìòù) I see the text displayed correctly.

If I try to assign with string value `edit_message`, I get the unknown character symbol. This is my code:

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
editText.setText("àèìòù");
```

I think it's an encoding problem, but it seem strange.
The string shouldn't be UTF-8 by default?

Comment: Add this in strings.xml and use context.getString(R.string.yourStringName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML entity-codes via *Html.fromHtml*:

```
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("&agrave;&eacute; ...");
```

A list of entity codes is available here:

http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html

You could use the method  [htmlEncode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode%28java.lang.String%29) of the TextUtils class to automaticaly convert your input-text to an encoded-format:

```
string encodedText = TextUtils.htmlEncode("àèìòù");
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(encodedText));
```

Comment: This works, but i have to write &agrave; instead of à each time. It's normal?

Comment: I enhanced my answer please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, this one is way better than having to write each time the single char.

Comment: One more thing: this is an android behavior? It's the first time for me that i have to write something like this to show an utf-8 character!

Comment: I can't tell you why excactly setText does not accept special characters. I never met this behaviour in any other environment also.